# Get dashboard ID and report ID using DAX or R in Power BI

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi

Is there a way to get the Power BI dashboard ID and report IDs, using DAX or R in the data model (I want to present them in the dashboard)?

The ID appears in the dashboard URL:

[image: Dashboard URL]